# Upgraded to Fancybox 2, Fancybox is now broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I was using jQuery v1.7.2 and fancybox v1.3.3 on a page on my site. I had some text which appeared in a Fancybox when a button was clicked (as you can see from the code it should also appear if a certain session attribute is present, but this is irrelevant to the problem).

I just upgraded to Fancybox 2, and now when I click the same button the content of my Fancybox appears on the very top of my webpage, and the Fancybox which pops up says "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later."

Below is the script and HTML from my page. All was working previously - the only parts I changed was one line under the comment "Add jQuery library" and the two lines under the comment "Add fancyBox"

```
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(function($) {    
            $(".doWhatsNew").each(function (i) {
                $(this).on("click", function () {           

                    jQuery('#whatnew').css('display','block');     
                    jQuery.fancybox({content:whatnew});
                });
            });
        });

        </script>               

        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            <% if(session.getAttribute("ATTRIBUTE") != null){ %>    
                var message = jQuery('#whatnew').css('display','block');     
                jQuery.fancybox({content:whatnew});
                <% session.removeAttribute("ATTRIBUTE");
            }%>         


            jQuery("#whatsnew").fancybox({
                'width'             : '65%',
                'height'            : '55%',
                'autoScale'         : false,
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'type'              : 'iframe'
            });     
        });
    </script>

<!-- HTML -->

        <div id="whatnew" style="display:none;">
        (What's New Text Here)
        </div>


    <button class="doWhatsNew">Retreive "What's New" Pop-Up</button>
```

Comment: You are referencing #whatSnew while I can only see a whatnew id in the page. Note the lack of an -s.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but this isn't the issue. The code works if I use jQuery v1.7.2 and fancybox v1.3.3 rather than the newer versions.